# Android Emulator flickering

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, archlinux, flicker

I've set up a Nexus 5X in Android Studio running Android Q:

[image]

When I launch it, there is always a huge flicker (see https://streamable.com/wdpf0).

I'm running on Arch Linux on an Intel Core i7-6500U. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 11):

1. In windows go to:
   C:\Users\'your username'\.android\avd\"Device Name".avd
2. Open config.ini in text editor.
3. change below lines as shown.

`hw.gpu.enabled = no`
`hw.gpu.mode = off`

If the problem persist or emulator crash, detach emulator from Tool Window.

1. File -> Settings -> Tools -> Emulator UnTick 'Launch in a ToolWindow'

Comment: Disabling the GPU in the config.ini file resolved the screen artifacts problem, but it negatively affects the emulator's performance.

Comment: I only had to detach the emulator from Tool Window, and the flickering was gone!